# Failed to connect. Is Docker Running?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have run the command `docker context create PikaServer --docker "host=ssh://pika_node"` and it seems to work just fine.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JEPV.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JEPV.png)

I can see the right container and the right image from the server. When I use the Docker Extension with VSCode I got the failed to connect error. Not sure why I am getting the error. Not sure it is a docker issue. It might be a VSCode issue.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esDxC.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esDxC.png)

From the terminal only, using "host=ssh://pika_node" is just fine, I can access the remote images and containers. However, with VSCode using Docker extension, it is just not possible to use the ssh alias `pika_node`.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saOfN.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saOfN.png)

How can I handle this error?

**UPDATE**

Be aware I use `ssh-jump`.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O1O4.png) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O1O4.png)

Comment: What's the error?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  Make sure the details necessary to reproduce the issue are in the question (not behind links) and in text form (not images).

Comment: The error is from VSCode, but not sure exactly what this is. When I use the context from the terminal, it is fine, but I can't see the images, containers, ... from vscode. This is where I got the error `Failed to connect. Is Docker Running?`.  So in other words, `docker context create PikaServer --docker "host=ssh://pika_node"` is a fine command line for docker (using the terminal), but it is not for Docker Extension (in VSCode) because I use `pika_node` a ssh alias. I tried to use the `username@host` related to `pika_node` but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Image 3 shows you the cause of your problem:

> The "host" part in the Docker endpoint string (ssh://username@host:port) must be either a globally-resolvable DNS machine name, or an IP address. Docker extension will not be able to use host aliases defined in the SSH configuration file.

And in Image 4 you've shown how you're using a host alias `pika_node`.

to resolve this, use the IP address of the docker host in your context:

`host=ssh://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

instead of using the pika_node alias to refer to it.